# Default template argument of a class template has no effect if placed after the definition of that class template

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Please consider the following example:

```
// Mind the default template argument
template <typename T = int>
struct Test;

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Test;

int main()
{
    Test<>       t;
    return 0;
}
```

The code above can be successfully compiled by MSVC 19, gcc 8 and clang 8. Just as expected.
Now let's move the default template argument to the definition of the class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct Test;

// Mind the default template argument
template <typename T = int>
struct Test
{
};

template <typename T>
struct Test;

int main()
{
    Test<>       t;
    return 0;
}
```

This works with all three compilers, too.

However, if I placed the default argument **after** the definition of the `Test` class template, then Visual Studio would refuse to compile the source and complain that

> line marked (!): too few template arguments

```
template <typename T>
struct Test;

template <typename T>
struct Test
{
};

// Mind the default template argument
template <typename T = int>
struct Test;

int main()
{
    Test<>       t;    // (!)
    return 0;
}
```

Is it a MSVC bug?
I think cppreference is quite clear on the subject: default template arguments on the definition and all declarations should be merged. No special exception is made for the declarations *following* the definitions, right?

Comment: Yes, it's visual studio bug. Visual studio's compiler is known to do strange things to templates.

Comment: perhaps add the language lawyer tag in case you are looking for supporting quotes from the standard

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bug.  Per [[temp.param]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.param#12)

> The set of default *template-arguments* available for use is obtained by merging the default arguments from all prior declarations of the template in the same way default function arguments are ([dcl.fct.default]).

Since `t` comes after

```
// Mind the default template argument
template <typename T = int>
struct Test;
```

the `int` default parameter should be considered and used since no parameter is specified.